# How to use SP2013 REST API on public-facing ASP.NET site using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have a public-facing ASP.NET site that does not have any authentication/authorization. It is strictly an external site that has information for anonymous users. I am trying to call list/library data in a secured SP2013 site and render the list/library items on the ASP.NET site. The SP2013 web app is on the same server and domain as the ASP.NET site, and both sites are running under the same IIS instance.

From what I understand, I have to use the cross-domain library to do this, since my desire is to use client-side code (i.e. JavaScript/JQuery) using an anonymous user. I recognize that using the server-side object model is another approach, and I am leveraging C# for certain functionality. Anyway, I'm having trouble where SP.RequestExecutor is saying I don't have an App Web URL defined. I'm struggling to find documentation on how to set that up. And the challenge also being that I really don't want to have appweburl and hosturl in the query string (if possible). If there is another way to do this, I'm def open to it. I just really want to leverage the REST API and execute the JS code using a service account (in theory).

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the correct approach using client side code however there are some additional steps required because of SharePoint 2013's security model. What you are creating is viewed by SharePoint as an externally hosted SharePoint app. Your application cannot authenticate to SharePoint 2013 anonymously; it must have an identity that SharePoint can assign permissions to.

To access any list within the "secured SP2013 site" your code will have to provision an app (which will reside at an App URL) to with which SharePoint can exchange security tokens. You have the option of using Azure as an access control provider or creating a STS trust with your application. Once it is set up, the app will have to be granted permissions it requires (in this case read access to the list) by the person who installs it to SharePoint and it can only be installed by someone who possesses at least the permission level on that list that the app requires.

For a step-by-step walkthrough on the security model I recommend Scott Hillier's book on SharePoint 2013 app development [Microsoft SharePoint 2013 App Development (Developer Reference)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735674981).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The part I'm having trouble with is finding the URL/place where I go to create a new "SharePoint App" and get the security/token info, and then how to incorporate that in the REST call. Do you either have code samples or a blog with steps on how to do this? I've scoured the internet and am still fumbling a bit. Thanks for your response.